# Spring Securing Web add css, js and images

Tags: java, javascript, css, spring

I want to add css, javascript and images to a spring 4 web application, i could give an example but I'm trying a spring tutorial:

Securing Web - http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

I added following changes:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Then i added a folder css with a simple css to the resources folder:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

p {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
```

Then i added the css to the home.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/dummy.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Security config is injected through the following java class:

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }
    }
```

Then when using the google debug it returns the code

```
Status Code:302 Found but the css is not applied.
```

Could anyone indicate the changes necessary to add to make this working?

Comment: I think you'r missing the root of the project in the `href` from the css. Also can you post the security config, maybe you secure the resource and, the client can't access it.

Comment: I Evgeni I have added the Security Config but even if I remove the security completely and try to access the browser returns the HTML code 404 Not Found.

Comment: Try to change `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/dummy.css"></link>` to `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@{/resources/css/dummy.css}"></link>`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, and I even removed the security but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the problem after some search, the changes need to be able to use the css in the example are:
Create the following dirs under src/main:

```
- webapp
- resources
- css
```

Then add the dummy.css and in the desired html use:

```
<link th:href="@{/resources/css/dummy.css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/dummy.css"></link>
```

Thanks to everyone that tried to help :)

Comment: In my case I had to add .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() on my Spring Security JavaConfig class. Your post helped me thought.

Comment: frustrating issue and wastes lot of time: 
If you're facing same issue try, this fixed mine : 

1- remove @EnableWebMVC from class extending WebMVCConfigurerAdapter (will mostly fix issue)

2- in webSecurityAdapter extending class inside onConfigure method add 

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll();

and when using Spring boot security with annotation u must put static resources inside src/main/resources/ <public> or <static> /css/apple.css

in views : <link href="<c:url value="css/apple.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">